# ]m moves to class definitions not method definitions inside nested classes

Tags: cursor-movement, cursor-motions, filetype-java

I am editing a java file.

`]m` takes me from one class to the next, instead of to the next method definition.

How do I get it to take me between methods?

Example:

```
public class Baz {
    public class Foo {
        public Foo() {
        }

        public void doFooOne() {
        }

        public void doFooTwo() {
        }
    }

    public class Bar {
        public Bar() {
        }

        public void doBarOne() {
        }

        public void doBarTwo() {
        }
    }
}
```

Putting cursor on `doFooOne` and typing `]m` jumps the cursor to `public class Bar {` instead of to `doFooTwo`.

Comment: Could you add a code snippet to illustrate the behaviour?

Comment: I feel like there’s a question about this already on this site (might be about C++ functions within a namespace block) but I can’t find it now.

Comment: @Rich well the problem seems to do with nesting, so the C++ functions being _inside_  a namespace block may have the same issue.

Comment: I guess this is the corresponding [bug](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3058)